# "Could not find a declaration file for module '@handsontable/react'" even though "d.ts" file exists

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, handsontable

I'm starting a new project with `vite+react+ts+swc` with below command following vite document.

`npm create vite@latest -- --template react-swc-ts`

And, I installed handsontable library with below command. (It also written in handsontable document.)

`npm install --save handsontable @handsontable/react`

However, When I try to use handsontable in my `App.tsx` file, It occurs two typescript errors.

```
// App.tsx
import { HotTable } from '@handsontable/react';
import { registerAllModules } from 'handsontable/registry';
```

```
src/App.tsx:6:26 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module '@handsontable/react'. '.../node_modules/@handsontable/react/es/react-handsontable.mjs' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  There are types at '.../node_modules/@handsontable/react/index.d.ts', but this result could not be resolved when respecting package.json "exports". The '@handsontable/react' library may need to update its package.json or typings.


src/App.tsx:7:36 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'handsontable/registry'. '.../node_modules/handsontable/registry.mjs' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  There are types at '.../node_modules/handsontable/registry.d.ts', but this result could not be resolved when respecting package.json "exports". The 'handsontable' library may need to update its package.json or typings.
```

Here is my `tsconfig.json`. (created by vite template)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

And I think there is no problem with handsontable library because it has `index.d.ts` normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in the Handsontable library.

https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/10448